# Memory being messed up while searching for relation in family tree

Tags: c++, class, wizard, backtracking, family-tree

I am implementing class of wizards in this code but I have a serious problem with finding relation in wizards family tree. I am using a back tracking method to find all relation between two nodes but memory will start to being messed up in the middle of the task and I have no idea what should I do.
Here you can see implementation of this class using C++.

```
#include "Wizard.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

Wizard::Wizard(string first_name, string surname, string occupation, string organization, string wand)
: first_name(first_name),surname(surname), occupation(occupation), organization(organization), wand(wand)
{
    this->married=0;
    this->wand="Dragon Hearstring";
    this->occupation="Auror";
    this->organization="Dumbledore Army";
};

void Wizard::set_first_name(string _name){
    this->first_name = _name;
}

void Wizard::set_surname(string _surname){
    this->surname = _surname;
}

void Wizard::set_occupation(string _occupation){
    this->occupation = _occupation;
}

void Wizard::set_organization(string _organization){
    this->organization = _organization;
}

void Wizard::set_wand(string _wand){
    this->wand = _wand;
}

string Wizard::get_name(){
    string name;
    name = first_name + " " + surname;
    return name;
}

string Wizard::get_occupation(){
    return occupation;
}

string Wizard::get_organization(){
    return organization;
}

string Wizard::get_wand(){
    return wand;
}

void Wizard::print_parents(){
    cerr << "Parents: ";
    for (int i=0; i<parents.size(); i++){
        cout << parents[i]->get_name();
        if ( i!= parents.size() -1){
            cout << " & ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Wizard::print_siblings(){
    cerr <<"Siblings: ";
    for (int i=0; i<siblings.size(); i++){
        cout << siblings[i]->get_name();
        if ( i < siblings.size() -1){
            cout << " & ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Wizard::print_spouse(){
    cerr <<"Spouse: ";
    if (married==1)
        cout << spouse->get_name();
    cout << endl;
}

void Wizard::print_children(){
    cerr <<"Children: ";
    for (int i=0; i<children.size(); i++){
        cout << children[i]->get_name();
        if ( i < children.size() - 1){
            cout << " & ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;   
}

void Wizard::operator*(Wizard& _spouse){
    this->married=1;
    _spouse.married=1;
    cout << this->get_name() << " and " << _spouse.get_name() << endl;
    this->spouse = &_spouse;
    _spouse.spouse = this;
    _spouse.print_spouse();
    vector< Wizard* > these_two;
    these_two.push_back(this);
    these_two.push_back(&_spouse);
    for (int i=0; i<this->children.size(); i++)
        children[i]->parents = these_two;
    for (int i=0; i<_spouse.children.size(); i++)
        children[i]->parents = these_two;
}

void Wizard::operator+(Wizard& _child){
    if (!search_in_vector(this->children,&_child))
        this->children.push_back(&_child);
    if (!search_in_vector(this->spouse->children,&_child))
        this->spouse->children.push_back(&_child);
    vector< Wizard* > these_two;
    these_two.push_back(this);
    these_two.push_back(this->spouse);
    _child.parents=these_two;
    _child.surname = this->surname;
    for (int i=0; i<this->children.size(); i++){
        if(!search_in_vector(_child.siblings,children[i]) &&     (children[i]!=&_child)){
            _child.siblings.push_back(children[i]);
            children[i]->siblings.push_back(&_child);
        }
    }
}

    void Wizard::print_relation_with(Wizard& john_doe){
    vector<string> path2;
    vector< vector< string > > path1;
    vector<Wizard*> nodes_in_the_way;
    nodes_in_the_way.push_back(this);
    if (this->get_name() == john_doe.get_name()){
        cout << this->get_name() << " is " << john_doe.get_name() << endl;
        return;
    }
    this-   >search_for_relation(*this,john_doe,path1,path2,nodes_in_the_way);
    if (path1.size() == 0){
        cout << "no relation" << endl;
        return;
    }
    path2=path1[0];
    for (int i=1;i<path1.size();i++){
        if (path1[i].size() < path2.size())
            path2=path1[i];
    }
    cout << this->get_name() << " is ";
    for (int i=0; i<path2.size(); i++)
        cout << path2[i] << " of ";
    cout << john_doe.get_name() << endl;
}

void Wizard::search_for_relation(Wizard& a,Wizard& b,vector<       vector<string> > &path1,vector<string> &path2,vector< Wizard* >    &nodes_in_the_way){
    cerr << "////////////" << endl;
    cerr << "IM INSIDE " << a.get_name() << " , SEARCHING FOR " <<     b.get_name() << " - " << path2.size() << endl;
    cout << "PATH: ";
    for (int i=0;i<nodes_in_the_way.size();i++)
        cout << nodes_in_the_way[i]->get_name() << "  ";
    cout << endl;
    a.print_spouse();
    a.print_children();
    a.print_parents();
    if (a.get_name() == b.get_name() && path2.size()==0){
        return;
    }
    if (a.get_name() == b.get_name() ){
        path1.push_back(path2);
        return;
    }   
    if (a.married){
        if (!search_in_vector(nodes_in_the_way,a.spouse)){
            path2.push_back("spouse");
            nodes_in_the_way.push_back(a.spouse);
            search_for_relation(*    (a.spouse),b,path1,path2,nodes_in_the_way);
            path2.pop_back();
            nodes_in_the_way.pop_back();
        }       
    }
    // parents
    for (int i=0;i<a.parents.size();i++){
        if (!search_in_vector(nodes_in_the_way,a.parents[i])){
            path2.push_back("child");
            nodes_in_the_way.push_back(a.parents[i]);
            search_for_relation(*    (a.parents[i]),b,path1,path2,nodes_in_the_way);
            path2.pop_back();
            nodes_in_the_way.pop_back();
        }   
    }
    // children
    for (int i=0;i<a.children.size();i++){
        if (!search_in_vector(nodes_in_the_way,a.children[i])){
            path2.push_back("parent");
            nodes_in_the_way.push_back(a.children[i]);
            search_for_relation(*    (a.children[i]),b,path1,path2,nodes_in_the_way);
            path2.pop_back();
            nodes_in_the_way.pop_back();
        }   
    }
}

///////////// NON-METHOD FUNCITONS ///////////////

bool search_in_vector(vector< Wizard* > a,Wizard* b){
    for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
        if (a[i]->get_name() == b->get_name())
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

So that was the code.
Here you can see the output after some back_tracking:

[image: Output]

Here you see that Harry's information has been messed up during last recursion and the executable file can't print his parents.

Please let me know that I'm doing wrong! Thanks!

Comment: *I have no idea what should I do* -- Step through your program using your debugger to see where your program takes a different path than you expected and/or inspect your variables.

Comment: Guaranteed you are stepping out of bounds somewhere. Change all of your vector accesses `[]` to `at()` and then use your debugger to see which one throws an exception.

Comment: What you should do is learn safe programming practices that make it logically impossible for common programming bugs -- such as stomping on memory, running off past the end of the array, and wild pointer dereferencing -- to occur. Like: using smart pointers instead of raw pointers; using iterators, using standard algorithms. Another thing you should do is edit your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: Please post a [mcve], which includes a `main` function with the data that duplicates the issue.  Second, there are functions such as `std::find_if` that you should be using to search the vector, and not need to code entire functions and `for` loops to find an element in a vector.